# Warning in function strlen - in C

Tags: c, warnings

i have function on `C`

```
int myFunction(Room* room, char** buffer) {

    int l1;
    l1 = strlen(*buffer);
.
.
.
    return l1
}
```

And after compile with `gcc` i get a warning on line `l1 = strlen(*buffer);`:

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strlen' [enabled by default]
```

What is is? How can i solve it?

Comment: `#include <string.h>`

Answer (score 2):

Include the correct header at the top of your source file:

```
#include <string.h>
```

To call a function you need to have a declaration for this function. `strlen` function declaration is in `string.h` standard header.

Comment: Oh, this easy problem make me angry :-D thank you :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I was wondering why would it give me a warning instead of an error if I didn't include <string.h>?